# set_start_method('spawn') resets logger configurations

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

Consider the following snippet:

```
import logging
import logging.config
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method

try:
    set_start_method('spawn')
except RuntimeError:
    pass


def log(logger):
    for _ in range(10):
        logger.info('FLAG2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {
        "version": 1,
        "formatters": {
            "timestamp": {
                "format": "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
            },
        },
        "handlers": {
            "stdout": {
                "level": "INFO",
                "formatter": "timestamp",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
            },
        },
        "loggers": {
            "some_logger": {
                "level": "INFO",
                "handlers": ["stdout"]
            }
         }
    }

    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

    logger = logging.getLogger("some_logger")

    for _ in range(10):
        logger.info('FLAG1')

    p = Process(target=log, args=(logger,))

    p.start()

    p.join()
```

This will print `FLAG1` ten times, including timestamps, `FLAG2` will not be written to stdout. If I remove the call to `set_start_method('spawn')`, both `FLAG1` and `FLAG2` are displayed and I imagine this is because the spawned thread is missing some global logger configuration created by `dictConfig`. Still, is there a way to pass a logger to a spawned thread and retain the same logging behaviour without also having to pass the logger configuration dictionary?

Comment: I'm confused. I'd expect your script to raise an exception while trying to pickle the reentrant lock created during the initialization of the StreamHandler ...

Comment: Huh, yeah I didn't think about that. I have had to clean up some pickle related problems in my actual project when switching to 'spawn'. But the conda above does not throw an exception for Python 3.6.8 (Anaconda).

Comment: I just tested with 3.6.4 on RHEL and Windows. Sure enough, it raised a TypeError for an unpicklable RLock in both environments. Now I wonder _how_ you cleaned up your pickle problems :) Anyway, I would refrain from trying to share loggers and (especially) handlers between processes. Having dedicated logging for each process is less of a pain. A logging dict is easier shared than a Logger (or rather Handler) instance.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll stick to handing around logging configs.